# Verified app consent screen still saying it isnt verified

Tags: google-oauth

I have submitted my OAuth app for Verification with Google. They have verified it, and confirmed that in an email. I can also see that the app is marked as verified in the Developer Console. I tested it when I received the email saying it had been verified, and also 2 days later, and it all worked as expected, so we released our product that used the OAuth.
Now, we always get the error:
"Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In."

Nothing has been changed in the app settings, and it still states it as verified.

I have emailed Google by replying back to the verification email a number of times, but haven't had a response.

Has anyone got any ideas, or know how else I can get in touch with Google about this?

Many Thanks,

Chris

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any solution for this ?